# Bad Gateway: The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server

Tags: php, apache

I have a built-in PHP development server running on a random port and I am trying to configure secure API requests with Apache Reverse Proxy.

Apache2 listens on port 443 and passes requests to the server, the server processes the request and passes the JSON response back to Apache2 but for some reason, there is an error.

Everything works well when I try to access the upstream server directly. There is no typo.
SSL and ReverseProxy work.
Servers are running on Ubuntu.
Mime mod is enabled and I have added json to the file formats Apache2 should serve in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf.

The PHP is most likely the culprit but how do I make it better? I've been trying to figure this out for a month now.

Or is there a better way to secure API requests to the PHP server? I tried to achieve this using tunnel but was not successful due to the constant occurrence of errors.

```
The PHP code on the upstream server.

header ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
header ("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8");
header ("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS,GET,POST,PUT,DELETE");
header ("Access-control-Max-Age: 3600");
header ("Access-Control-Allow-header: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
header ("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");

echo json_encode (array ("BODY"=>"hello world", "status_code_header"=>"HTTP/1.1 200 Ok"));
```

**apache2.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

     ServerName ...
     ErrorLog ...
     CustomLog ...
     
     SSLEngine On
     SSLCertificateFile ...
     SSLCertificateKeyFile ...
 
     ProxyPass / http://localhost:port/ retry=1 acquire=3000 timout=600 Keepalive=On
     ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:port/

</VirtualHost>
```

**Apache2 error.log**

> bad HTTP/1.1 header returned by /person/